# How to do a push notification with picture like the Photo App

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, apple-push-notifications

In WWDC 2014 videos I saw how to create a notification widget, interactive push, etc. But I can't figure out how to send a push notification with a picture like the Photo App does in iOS 8. Is this something us mortals can do? Or something only Apple Apps can?

[image: photo push]

Comment: unfortunately that looks a privilege of Gods only, mortals cannot do such thing via Apple's push notification servers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because the push notification payload can be up to 256 bytes long.
Take a look at [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) regarding push notifications here

Comment: From that page in Apple's docs... "In iOS 8 and later, the maximum size allowed for a notification payload is 2 kilobytes; Apple Push Notification service refuses any notification that exceeds this limit. (Prior to iOS 8 and in OS X, the maximum payload size is 256 bytes.)" Im sure you can't fit a pic there but you could send a url download in background and show it. Im sure as a notification center widget is doable but I can't figure out how to do it as a push notification.